# Pretty printing of a QHash with CDB under Qt Creator

Tags: c++, qt, debugging, qt-creator

I'm using the following compilers:

- MinGW 4.9.2 32Bit
- Microsoft Visual C++ Compiler 12.0 (x86)

with the following debuggers, respectively:

- GNU gdb 7.8 for  MinGW 4.9.2 32Bit
- CDB (\Windows Kits\8.1\Debuggers\x86\cdb.exe)

with Qt Creator 3.5.0 and Qt 5.4.2.

What I would like to see is the pretty printed ("high level") interpretation of a QHash within the debugger watch view. See e.g. this post: https://blog.qt.io/blog/2009/06/22/peek-and-poke/

The pretty printing works with gdb + MinGW but not with CDB + MSVC2012. In the latter, I can only see the 'low level' interpretation.

What do I have do to get this work with CDB + MSVC2012 too?

Comment: what do you mean by `high level`? You should be able to explain it easily.

Comment: @UmNyobe The question is about pretty printing of Qt data types under the debugger.

Comment: Is your problem limited to `QHash`, with other Qt types pretty printing as they should? Or do you get no support for pretty printing of any Qt types at all?

Comment: I'm not getting pretty printing for any Qt type,

Answer (score 0):

You will need to add a correct debugging addin dll into the visual studio installation directory `C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio ${num}\Common7\IDE` or preferably the add-in directory ( default is  `%USERPROFILE%\Documents\Visual Studio ${num}\Addins`).

Qt already provide a complete set of tools for MSVC integration which can be built from one of the [qt git **vstool** project](http://git://code.qt.io/qt-labs/vstools.git).

There is a [wiki which provide a step by step guide](https://wiki.qt.io/Visual_Studio_Add-in) to make it work. Basically :

- get the project from repository
- create the solution files
- build the correct solution, as there is one for each pair `Qt4\Qt5 x VsVersion`
- Copy the target dll to the addin directory.